# About Ubuntu cloud Server

Tags: cloud

How to install and deploy applications on **Ubuntu Cloud Server** ?
 What's the difference between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Cloud live image?

Answer (score 0):

This question is better posed at https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/

Comment: Hmm I guess you COULDN'T just flag it. StackExchange needs to add some feature for that.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser, he can flag it and ask a moderator to move it to openstack if he feels it needs to move.